# Likelihood test between two distributions for given data

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, lognormal-distribution, likelihood-ratio

I have samples from an unknown distribution. Lets say that I can get as many samples as I want. Now, I have two hypotheses. One is that the unknown distribution is log-normal and the second is that this is a normal distribution. How do I do the likelihood test to determine which distribution explains the data better.

PS: the problem is not exactly to understand the distribution of the unknown data, but for me to understand how to do likelihood test between these two distributions.

Comment: Do you know how to do hypothesis testing for parameters?

Comment: @JoaquinSan It's not clear how that question relates to the issue here.

Comment: @dinesh 1. Have you done any likelihood ratio test before? 2. Why do you want to do this with a formal hypothesis test rather than in some other way? 3. What's your *null* here? If you don't have one, then why *test*?

Comment: @Glen_b 1. No, I haven't done LRT before. But I want to learn it. 2. I want to learn how to do it this way. 3. Why not?

Comment: 1. I wouldn't start with this situation to learn LRTs. 2. Even if that doesn't really make sense in this case? What would you learn from that? 3. Without a null there's nothing to apply a NHST *to*. ... so it sounds like you should take a step back and consider what you really want to find out. What's the underlying issue?